# phpbb3 cache issues

Tags: caching, templates, phpbb3

i have an issue with caching of templates in phpbb3. i have made changes to a template in the admin control panel and saved it, then cleared the template cache through the "purge cache" and i don't see changes reflecting on the forum, but the change WAS saved in the admin control panel. i next edited the template file manually (not through the admin control panel) and uploaded my altered template file and deleted all the files from the cache directory and i still see no changes. can anyone tell me is there anywhere else that the cache files are stored? also, when i try to delete the cache for a specific file through the admin control panel in the styles section and selecting the "cache" link the page says it was deleted but the cache seems to remain. can anyone tell me if there's more than one place that the cache files are stored?? thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

I realize the is a very old post, but I've had the same problems this weekend, so apologies for bringing it back...

If you edit a style from the ACP and phpBB3 can't write to the *whole* style folder, it copies the entire style to the database, where it now overrides the files on the server. The "Purge Cache" button will now revert back to the version **stored in the database**

To fix this, go back to the ACP where you edited the style and click the "Export" button th get the modified version of the style in a file version, then click the  "Refresh" button. This will nuke the database version of the style.

Now, since you probably *wanted* those changes, replace the style files with the ones you just downloaded. Make any further changes to the those files, purge the cache again, and stay away from the "Edit" button in the ACP unless that's the **only** way you're going to edit the styles.